# malloc incorrect checksum in getaddrinfo

Tags: c, sockets, malloc

I frequently (about 70% of the time) get the error

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1567c574: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

in this line of code

```
getaddrinfo(baseServer, "http", &hints, &serverinfo);
```

Now, when I check the values of these, `baseServer` is a valid string (usually `www.a-cstudios.com`), `"http"` is obviously never freed to cause this error, `hints`is a `struct addrinfo` that is filled out with correct values, as it should be, and `serverinfo` is `NULL`, which I believe it is supposed to be. If all these values are correct, and I never free any object here, why do I get the error in this line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't that you're freeing something here. The problem isn't even *here*. The [`getaddrinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html) function has to allocate storage for the linked list of `addrinfo` structures that it returns, so it must be calling [`malloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html) under the hood. And `malloc()` is noticing that somewhere else in your program, something has written into a free block, and is kindly reporting it.

You can help prevent that sort of thing (writing into memory you no longer own) by religiously enforcing a policy of always setting pointers to `NULL` as soon as you free them. Also, valgrind.

<sub>Well, OK, you can help prevent that sort of thing by *not using pointers after you free them*, but making sure to always set pointers to NULL immediately after freeing will help you find the places where are are using them.</sub>

Comment: I would use valgrind, but I don't believe that is possible when testing on an iPhone.

Comment: Good point. I guess you'll just have to use rigorous programming methodology to ensure correctness, then.

Comment: `#define FREEANDNULL(p) do {free(p); (p)=NULL;} while (0);` could help in most of the cases.

Comment: You need to be careful with macros that double-evaluate the passed argument. (Imagine trying to loop through an array of pointers, freeing them as you go.)

Comment: I tested the same function on Mac using Valgrind, and it pointed out what I was doing wrong. It turns out I was writing over the bounds of a `char` array.

Comment: No, not completely wrong. I was right about your code writing into memory it doesn't own, but wrong about how/why.